# Como agregar una imagen de fondo a un Hbox en javafx

Tags: javafx

```
Label label1 = new Label("¿Como acompañar un buen vino ?");
label1.setFont(new Font("Berlin Sans FB", 24));

HBox hb = new HBox();
hb.getChildren().addAll(label1);
hb.setSpacing(10);
```